# Remote Desktop: multiple users viewing same desktop session

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

Is it possible to have two people view the same remote desktop?

That is, both people log in using the same user account and they see the same desktop session.

The intention is for collaboration / tech support. Ideally, both users would be able to control the session, however, a solution where one user is view-only would be ok.

Server is Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Google for "session shadowing". Use `qwinsta` to see id of connections and use `shadow x` to shadow a session where `x` = the id of the connection.

Answer (score 5):

This is possible from Terminal Services Manager (tsadmin) and user's Remote Control tab in AD
In TSAdmin on the server that the user's logged into, right-click their RDP session and select the "Remote Control" tab.

[image: ADUC User Remote Control tab]

Answer (score 3):

It's not strictly technically possible with TS\RDS but as TomTom stated, an administrator can "shadow" a user by initiating a remote control session of the users TS\RDS session.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not easy.

An administrator can pull himself into an already established session using "special tools" (check remote desktop administrator). User gets a notification.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour with [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/index.html)

Comment: Yeah, but VNC can not have any multi user capability.

Comment: Only on MSWindows.

Answer (score 0):

Share the RDP session desktop with the cross platform open source java based ldap auth webhuddle, then an unlimited number of people can view / control the session.
webhuddle.sf.net
Get a version from 2007 as the project was taken over with spam.