# Multiple users in a single session of Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, rdp

I would like to know if it is possible to have multiple users connected for viewing the same remote desktop.

The server is running under Windows Server 2012 Standard Edition.

This question is the same as [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/177640/remote-desktop-multiple-users-viewing-same-desktop-session) but for Windows Server 2012 Standard Edition (since Terminal Services doesn't exist anymore in 2012).

Comment: A user with the appropriate permissions can shadow another RDS session but there's no way for two users to share a single session. That functionality just doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

It should work the same in Windows 2012 as much as I can tell. I don't see a reason why not.
The Terminal Service have been renamed to Remote Desktop Services, all the rest of the functionality is preserved.

Comment: But how do I do that? I know that Terminal Service is now Remote Desktop Services, but I still can't find the directive to configure RDS for allowing multiple users in a single session of Remote Desktop.

Comment: Start -> All Programs -> Administrative Tools -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration.
Double-click RDP-TCP, navigate to Remote Control Tab.

Comment: Vegas I know how to access RDP configuration in Windows Server 2012. What I want to know is **how to configure RDP for allowing multiple users in a single remote desktop session**.

Comment: You would have to be more specific, the functionality of the remote control is explained in the topic that you linked. You can have 2 users as much as I know, if this what you asking for. Not more.